# Problem with installing gnome shell extentions via chrome

Tags: 20.04, gnome, google-chrome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I can't install any extentions from https://extensions.gnome.org/. When I swithed the button, nothing happens, no pop-ups for accepting the installation. When I reload the page, the button switches back to OFF.  I'm using Google Chrome, also tried Firefox, but it didn't solve the problem.
A few months earlier everything worked fine.

*I've already installed gnome-tweaks and gnome-extentions.

**I reinstalled chrome-gnome-shell but still no diffirence.

Ubuntu LTS 20.04. Gnome Shell version 3.36

Comment: Difficult to tell what the problem is if both chrome-gnome-shell and the browser plugin are correctly installed. Could you try temporarily moving out your current browser profile so a factory default one is created on next browser start, or even making a new user account and see if it works there? This allows to see if the issue is system wide or only within your current account.

Comment: Went out of my account and tried again - no diffirence. Also deleted chrome via apt purge and reinstalled it. Nothing changed.

Comment: Next one to try is to disable all your current extensions. Another thing to try is to temporarily create a new account, see if it works there.

Comment: It seems to be some trouble with Ubuntu cause I just got a system update and everything works.

Comment: So you mean that now, your problem is solved after the update?

Comment: Yep, absolutely